# How to display direction arrows in the map marker for google maps v2 android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I want to display markers like these below on my android map application. I Know I have to use custom marker for this I also have the angle calculated but I don't know how to display the arrow on the marker.

Any pointers will be helpful and Thanks in advance.

[image]