# Arrow direction header pointer in google map marker for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google map v2,everything works fine from viewing the map to applying polyline between markers.However there is one thing that I need to accomplish, it is to put arrow header inside the commonly used map marker.
The arrow must rotate or point to the direction of the next location and so on. here's the image looks like 
[map_marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Yg0.png)
I have tried using only the arrow alone and it works fine with the use of .rotation(bearing) but my boss wants it inside the commonly used marker and only the arrow will move.They have a working sample but it works only in the browser using javascript.I haven't found samples or at least documentation about it on the internet only this similar question 
[How to display direction arrows in the map marker for google maps v2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693969/how-to-display-direction-arrows-in-the-map-marker-for-google-maps-v2-android) but unfortunately no one answered. I have also tried

`.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(R.drawable.arrow_header)))`

but the both the marker and arrow moves

I have done everything to accomplish this task and this would be my last resort just to inform my boss that just in case there is no way that it'll work on android. Thank you..

Comment: So you want to only move that black arrow inside your yellow marker?

Comment: @R.R.M yes that is what I need to execute..

Comment: I think you have to change marker itself instead of setting bearing. How will you be able to change image inside a image?

Comment: yeah thats right..well I think I need to create array of images, for each degree then call its index if  the condition meets the right degree of next location..now I need to know how to get the degree of a certain location..

Comment: You can use bearing for that.

Comment: the first thing that comes into my mind is to apply the properties of widget analog clock , where you can set the minute and hour pointer to a certain degree. but its kinda tricky

Comment: @R.R.M  thanks for your response..very well appreciated

Comment: You can try that. And no need of thanks. :)